# Returning value from a function in shell script

Tags: bash, function, shell, return-value

I would like to pass an argument to a function and return a calculated value from it to be stored for further process. Below is the sample code.

```
#!/bin/bash

test()
{
    echo $1

    c=$(expr $1 + "10000")

    return $c
}

var=$(test 10)

echo $var
```

I would like to get the value of c stored in var. Can anyone please help in this case.

Comment: Despite the word "string" in the above proposed duplicate, it doesn't strictly have to be a string. The point is that you can only _return_ an unsigned byte (0-255) from a shell function.

Answer (score 2):

The "return value" of a function as you used it is stdout.
"return" will set exit status ($?), which you probably have no use for.
"test" is probably a bad choice of name, since it's taken (qv. `man test`).
So:

```
$ Test() { expr $1 + 10000; }
$ var=$(Test 10)
$ echo $var
10010
```

Comment: Thank you :) Its working...
I will not use test as my function name. This was just a sample, but my mistake in naming.
thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

if all you wish to do is add 10000 to your input, then a function is overkill. for this, wouldnt this work?

```
your_arg=10
var=$(( ${your_arg}+10000 ))
echo $var
```

Comment: For an example I pasted this simple code. I am using another function that converts the time (HH:MM) to seconds and this is being called many times.

Comment: This does not answer the OP, they are seeking to compute and return a value from a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code.

```
#!/bin/bash
```

It works but it is no good idea to define a function called `test`, because [`test` is a standard Unix program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_(Unix)).

```
test()
{
```

Write debug output to standard error (&2) instead of standard output (&1). Standard output is used to return data.

```
  echo "$1" >&2
```

Declare variables in functions with `local` to avoid side effects.

```
  local c=$(expr "$1" + "10000")
```

Use `echo` instead of `return` to return strings. `return` can return only integers.

```
  echo "$c"
}

var=$(test 10)
```

If unsure always quote arguments.

```
echo "$var" >&2
```